# Help solving a system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the third order linear differential equation:

$x'''- 2x''- 4x'+ 8x = 0.$

Given that $x(0) = 4$, $x'(0) = 16$, and $x''(0) = 16$, find the general solution to the corresponding first-order system.

I know that if I set $x_1 = x$, $x_2 = x_1'$, and $x_3 = x_2'$, I can generate the following system of equations:

$x_1' = x_2$,

$x_2' = x_3$,

$x_3' = -8x_1+4x_2+2x_3$.

I have got 2 (multiplicity of 2) and -2 (multiplicity of 1) for eigenvalues, but I'm not sure how to finish from here.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out, I wrote a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your equation. Looking at your expression for $x_3$ it should be:

$$x'''- 2x''- 4x'+ 8x = 0$$

...and the characteristic equation is:

$$r^3-2r^2-4r+8=0$$

$$(r^3+8)-(2r^2+4r)=0$$

$$(r+2)(r^2-2r+4) -2r(r+2)=0$$

$$(r+2)(r^2-4r+4)=0$$

$$(r+2)(r-2)^2=0$$

$$r_1=-2, \quad r_{2,3}=2$$

So the solution to your equation is:

$$x(t)=C_1e^{-2t}+C_2e^{2t}+C_3te^{2t}$$

Constants can be evaluated from your initial conditions. You should be able to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the equation is meant to be $x'''-2x''-4x'+8x=0$, in which case its characteristic polynomial is indeed $(r-2)^2(r+2)$ and the rest of the post makes sense.

The general solution is

$x(t)=Ae^{-2t} +(Bt+C)e^{2t}$

for constants $A, B, C$. So we have

$x(0) = A+C = 4$

$x'(0) = -2A + B +2C = 16$

$x''(0) = 4A + 4B + 4C = 16$

Now solve these simultaneous equations in $A,B,C$ to find the specific solution that meets your boundary conditions.